# Find average of row and column groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the states with the highest average total revenue and be able to see states with the 40-45th highest average, 35-40th, etc for all states from 1992-2016.

Data is organized in a dataframe in the below picture. So ideally I could have another column like the following. I think this is what I am trying to do.

```
STATE // YEAR // TOTAL_REVENUE // AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE

ALABAMA // 1992 // 5000 // 6059

ALABAMA // 1993 // 4000 // 6059

ALASKA // 1992 // 3000 // 2059

ALABAMA // 1996 // 6019 // 6059
```

[image]

Is this possible to do? I am not sure if I am stating what I want to do correctly and not sure what I am looking for google wise to figure out a way forward.

Comment: Can you post your dataframe (a subsample with around 10 - 15 rows is fine) as text? Will be much easier for us to test any code.

Comment: `df.groupby('STATE')['TOTAL_REVENUE'].transform('sum')` you can then apply some statistical methods to find your highest quartiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your input looks like:

```
STATE       YEAR    TOTAL_REVENUE
Michigan    2001    1000
Michigan    2002    2000
California  2003    3000
California  2004    4000
Michigan    2005    5000
```

Then just do:

```
df['AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE'] = np.nan

states = df['STATE'].tolist()
states = list(set(states))

for state in states:
    state_values = df[df['STATE'] == state]
    revenues = state_values['TOTAL_REVENUE'].tolist()
    revenues = [float(x) for x in revenues]
    avg = sum(revenues)/len(revenues)
    df['AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE'].loc[state_values.index] = avg
```

which gives you:

```
     STATE     YEAR       TOTAL_REVENUE  AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE
0    Michigan  2001           1000        2666.666667
1    Michigan  2002           2000        2666.666667
2  California  2003           3000        3500.000000
3  California  2004           4000        3500.000000
4    Michigan  2005           5000        2666.666667
```

Comment: This is bad practice. You don't want to use loops with pandas. You can replace your whole code with simply using: `df['AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE'] = df.groupby('STATE')['TOTAL_REVENUE'].transform('mean')`

Comment: You're not looping through pandas here, you're looping through a list of states- and then setting a group of indices equal to averages. The individual looping of rows in pandas is bad practice though, agreed. But upvoted because if your method works (haven't tested) definitely would go with that over mine!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored in a pandas dataframe called df with STATE as index, then you can try:

```
df.set_index("STATE",inplace=True)
avg_revenue = df.groupby(level=0)["TOTAL_REVENUE"].agg("mean")
df["AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE"] = avg_revenue.loc[df.index]
df = df.sort_values(by="AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE",ascending=False)
```

Regarding the "40-45th highest average", I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. But you could do this for instance:

```
import numpy as np

bin = (np.array([0.40, 0.45]) * len(df)).astype(int)

df.iloc[bin[0]:bin[1],:]

# Or with quantiles
min_q,max_q = (0.40, 0.45)
avg = df.AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE

df.loc[(avg >= avg.quantile(min_q)) & (avg <= avg.quantile(max_q)), :]
```

Or maybe you want to bin your data every 5 state in order of AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE?

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("STATE")["AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE"].agg("first")
n_bins = int(df_grouped.shape[0] / 5)

bins = (pd.cut(df_grouped,bins=n_bins)
    .reset_index()
    .groupby("AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE")
    .agg(list)
)
```

Comment: I cannot have STATE as an index because STATE is listed once per year for 25 years. The index is simply 0,1,2,3, etc.

I like the idea of binning my data every 5 states in order of AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE, but I need to generate values for AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE first. I don't currently have any

Comment: You can have a repeated index, pandas can deal with it. Look at my edited answer